# Update a list in Usercontrol from another Usercontrol

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF app development and I have a problem to update a list in one user control from another user Control.Basically I have a MainWindow in which I have two user control for which one contains a list and another user control contains an excel Import .I have to update the List user control from the excel Import user control .I could successfully read all excel content in a list but how could I pass those list to List user control

Comment: Both UserControls should operate on a common view model. Search the web for MVVM.

Comment: Are you using MVVM?

Comment: Is there any other way to do other than MVVM

Comment: One control could have a property that is bound to a property of the other control. Take a look at data binding.

Comment: @SreekanthTN if each user control has separate view model you can use something like event aggregator pattern, https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/  otherwise if there is only one viewmodel for the main window, then those user controls on it will automatically have access to the data context of the main window and all its properties